# Placing diamond shape onto centered line between two columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to add a vertically centered line between two columns with a diamond-like shape. I know I could achieve it using the border property, but the problem is that a border is already lined up around the columns.

How can I achieve that?

```css
.box {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box p,
.box a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 45%);
  grid-column-gap: 8%;
}

.rhomb {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 30px;
  border: none;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
  transform-origin: 0 100% 0deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rhomb"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydz8jjbs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on a pseudo-elements like this:

```css
.box {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box p,
.box a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 46%);
  grid-column-gap: 8%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want more than one diamond you can use pseudo-element with boxes:

```css
.box {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.box p,
.box a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 46%);
  grid-column-gap: 8%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid .box:nth-child(2n)::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  left:-12%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.grid .box:nth-child(2n):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 2px;
  background: red;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -9%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, diamond positioned nicely, but still need that vertical line coming through it. Any help with that?

Comment: Works great! Thanks, only if there would be a possibility of having more than one diamond positioned in the middle between two boxes. Currently its only one in the center between all four.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing, if its too big favor thats fine, but the diamond is slightly off on mobile, is there anything that can be done apart from targetting media queries?

Comment: Ok, I figured that out myself. Everything is flying! Thanks!